# Merge values from two columns to overwrite NAs in same row in R

Tags: r, replace, merge, na

I have two columns (a and b) that I want to 'merge', such that 'a' overwrites values in 'b' only where there is a NA.

Essentially, I want the PAV and SAV in 'b' to stay.

I tried the following code:

```
MergingTABLE$c <- ifelse(is.na(MergingTABLE$b), MergingTABLE$a, MergingTABLE$b)
```

but it gives me numbers instead of copying the values over.

```
MergingTABLE <- data.frame(a = c("NOO","NOO","POR","NOO","SAV","WAT","SAV","PAV","COM","WAT"),
                          b = c(NA,NA,"PAV",NA,"SAV",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

I want an output column that is the combination of both, but uses the value in b when both a and b have non-NA values.

Comment: You probably have those columns as factors, since that's the default of `data.frame`. You can add `stringsAsFactors = F` when you create the data frame, or you can wrap the columns in `ifelse` with `as.character`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
MergingTABLE %>% 
  mutate(c = if_else(is.na(b), a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table:

```
library('data.table')
setDT(MergingTABLE)
MergingTABLE[!is.na(b), c := b]
MergingTABLE[is.na(b), c := a]
```